# Create compile script for java project Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, compilation

I have a large project made in java (approx 20 classes) that I compile using the Eclipse IDE. However, I need to be able to create a script for this project that runs on Windows and can be compiled using the command prompt. I have a build.xml that uses ant, how do I invoke it from the command prompt?

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Answer (score 0):

Set ANT_HOME as an environment variable to the root directory of your ant installation and append %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH variable.

Then open command prompt, change directory to root of your project and type:

> ant

This will run the default target specified in your build.xml file.

For more options:
 https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html